# Constraints are not working for views in keyboard extension

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, ios-keyboard-extension

**How I set my constraints**

[image]

**How I add this uiview**

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "keyboard", bundle: nil)

keyboardView = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

self.inputView.addSubview(keyboardView)
```

**How it looks like in the simulator**

[image]

Does anyone have similar issues?

Comment: what is the height and width of xib???

Comment: hey @Bhavin, the xib has a height 216 and width 375. And I also inspect the viewDidLayoutSubviews method. When viewDidLayoutSubviews is first called, UIInputView has a frame (0 0; 0 0), this view also has a frame of (0 0; 0 0); and the second time viewDidLayoutSubviews is called,  UIInputView has a frame(0 0; 375 216), this view also has a frame of (0 0; 375 216). Very bizarre.

Comment: yes...i thought may be the height and width of xib is not set up correctly....